# Deployed application shuts itself down immediately

Tags: rest, http, go, kubernetes, gorilla

I have a Go rest API application. And I Dockerized it and deployed it to Kubernetes.
It is working as it should on my local.

But in Kubernetes, the application shuts down itself, and the pod is restarted.

It doesn't print anything, any log, or any fail.

```
import ( 
" github.com/gorilla/mux"
"net/http"
"log"

)   
func main() {
    controller := controllers.Controllers{}
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/customer", controller.GetCustomer()).Methods("GET")
    router.HandleFunc("/customer", controller.InsertCustomer()).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc("/healthcheck", controller.HealthCheck())

    addr := ":" + os.Getenv("PORT")
    srv := &http.Server{Addr: addr, Handler: router}

    go func() {
        if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("listenAndServe failed: %v", err)
        }
    }()
    println("reached here")
}
```

Surprisingly it prints the "reached here" line when I look at the logs.
I checked the `env` variable, and it is also correct.
I suspect that the call to `listenAndServe` fails, but I couldn't find a reasonable answer for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the `main()` function ends, your app ends as well. It does not wait for other non-main goroutines to finish. See [Spec: Program execution:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution)

> Program execution begins by initializing the main package and then invoking the function `main`. When that function invocation returns, the program exits. It does not wait for other (non-`main`) goroutines to complete.

Since you start the listerer in a new goroutine, there's nothing "blocking" `main()`, there's nothing left to do (after printing `"reached here"`), so your app ends. Note that the builtin [`println()`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#println) prints to the standard error, that's why you may not see any logs (standard output and standard error may be saved / redirected to different places).

The easiest "fix" is to start listening in `main()`:

```
srv := &http.Server{Addr: addr, Handler: router}

if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("listenAndServe failed: %v", err)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. The code was like this. And then I thought maybe I should write in a goroutine. And tried the one that I pasted here.

Comment: I mean the same problem happens. Application shuts down and the pod is restarted.

Comment: @kuzua This works for me. If it doesn't work for you, you must see something in the log. And don't use `println()`, use `log.Println()`.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I updated it as a log.Println() but this is so weird. Now I cannot see "reached here" line at all.

Comment: @kuzua That's normal, because `ListenAndServe()` blocks and doesn't return if everything goes well. So if the server starts and listens, printing statements after that won't get reached and executed.